# Motion detection alarm that calls back

Tags: arduino-nano

I need help. I am making motion detector that calls you when sensor activates 
and i have done the code for that, but the thing is i am beginner and i need to make it when it first time boots i send a message with the number that will be called when sensor activates

`

```
int LED1 = 12;
int GND1 = 13;
int LED2 = 8;
int GND2 = 9;
int pirOutput = 5;
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(LED1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(GND1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(GND2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pirOutput, INPUT);

  digitalWrite(pirOutput, LOW);
  digitalWrite(GND1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(GND2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);
  delay(15000);
  digitalWrite(LED1, HIGH);

}
void loop()
{
  if (digitalRead(pirOutput) == HIGH)
  {
    digitalWrite(LED2, HIGH);
    Serial.println("OK");
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("ATD+381xxxxxxxx;");
    delay(15000);
    Serial.println("ATH");
    digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);
    delay(1000);
  }
}
```

that is the code i found and it works fine for me

Comment: I that code is fine for you, what exactly is your Question?

Comment: what does this mean? `i send a message with the number that will be called` ..... where are you sending a message?